# Using sscanf to parse a substring/float

Tags: c, parsing

I'm sending an AT command to a modem and getting this response (I'm using C):

```
\r\nOK\r\n\r\n+RSRP: 164,6200,\"-090.20\",\r\r\n+RSRQ: 164,6200,\"-07.30\",\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
```

The whole line is a C string. I need to use sscanf to readout the values in quotes, (-090.20 and -07.30). I'm having a really hard time. How would you solve this?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: `Any suggestions?` This question is too broad. Research C language. Learn about the tools `scanf` that you want to use. [Buy a good book about C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Research existing libraries that use AT commands, at least on github. Research the documentation of Heyes protocol and documentation of your device.  Eat healthy. Exercise. You might be interested in [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) maybe in [fmemopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html). Please read [how-to-ask].

Comment: Please read about [how do we ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The whole line is a C string
>
> I need to use sscanf to readout the values in quotes

The code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char input[] = "\r\nOK\r\n\r\n+RSRP: 164,6200,\"-090.20\",\r\r\n+RSRQ: 164,6200,\"-07.30\",\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
    char value1[101];
    char value2[101];
    int ret = sscanf(input, "%*[^\"]\"%100[^\"]\"%*[^\"]\"%100[^\"]", value1, value2);
    if (ret != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Matching error\n");
        abort();
    }
    printf("value1=%s\n", value1);
    printf("value2=%s\n", value2);
}
```

outputs:

```
value1=-090.20
value2=-07.30
```

Short description of parts used in format string used in `sscanf`:

- `%*[^\"]` - Ignore everything up until a `"`
- `\"` - match a `"`
- `%100[^\"]` - match up to 100 characters up to a `"`

You could use GNU extension `%m[\^"]` to dynamically allocate the string instead of specifying constant max size.

Comment: There was a GNU extension which allowed `%a...` for automatic allocation, but Posix Issue 7 (2008) adopted the `m`  modifier for that purpose, so it's a Posix standard extension, not just glibc.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk for taking the time to explain with a concrete example! Much appreciated. Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

**Not with `scanf`, but also a possibility:**

You could use `strtok` to separate the wanted values and `atof` to convert them to double. Be aware that unlike `strtod` (which is a bit more complicated to use), `atof` does not offer error handling. The values can be extracted using the following function, for example:

```c
#include <string.h> // For strtok
#include <stdlib.h> // For atof

void scanValues(char* input, double* value1, double* value2) {
    char* sep;
    
    sep = strtok(input, "\""); // replaces the first \" with \0
    sep = strtok(NULL, "\"");  // replaces the second \" with \0,
    *value1 = atof(sep);       // sep points to the first wanted value
    
    // Same for the second value:
    sep = strtok(NULL, "\"");
    sep = strtok(NULL, "\"");
    *value2 = atof(sep);
}
```

It could be called as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  // For printf

int main() {
    double value1, value2;
    char input[] = "\r\nOK\r\n\r\n+RSRP: 164,6200,\"-090.20\",\r\r\n+RSRQ: 164,6200,\"-07.30\",\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
    
    scanValues(input, &value1, &value2);
    
    printf("%f %f\n", value1, value2);
}
```